# matlab matrix reconstruction ideas

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an n-by-n matrix. I delete the row i-th and the column j-th from this matrix in order to work with a smaller matrix.
When I finish the job with this new matrix I would like to sum this smaller matrix to the old n*n one but avoiding any sum on the i-th row and j-th column. I think that this is a problem of matrix partitioning.
Any idea?

EDIT: I had the following idea, what's your opinion about it?

```
n_real=5;
%DEFINITION OF THE ADJUNCT SYSTEM
M_real(:,j)=[];  %removing column j from the mass matrix
M_real(i,:)=[];  %removing row i from the mass matrix
K_real(:,j)=[];  %removing column j from the stifness matrix
K_real(i,:)=[];  %removing row i from the stifness matrix
K=K_real;  
M=M_real;

AUX_DM=zeros(n_real);
AUX_DK=zeros(n_real);
for k=1:n_real      %rows index
for l=1:n_real      %columns index
    if l ~= i && k ~= j
        AUX_DM=DM_opt(k,l);     
        AUX_DK=DK_opt(k,l); 
    elseif l == i && k ~= j
        l=l+1;
    elseif k == j && l ~= i
        k=k+1;
    elseif k == j && l == i
        k=k+1;
        l=l+1;
    end
end
end

M_real_mod=M_real+AUX_DM;
K_real_mod=K_real+AUX_DK;
```

Comment: Show a [mcve] please

Comment: I have no idea about how to do it, that's why i am asking for ideas (even a pseudo code is ok), then i can try to implement it

Comment: Edit your question by giving an example of the input matrix and the desired output. It is obvious that you don’t have the code but show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Ok i did it. thanks

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you're trying to do. Sample inputs, actual outputs, and desired outputs are as much a part of a [mcve] as code. What do you mean by "a problem of matrix partitioning"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to add the new "smaller" array to old array, but omitting specific row and column. You can try creating new array with following code:

```
Z([1:i-1, i+1:n], [1:j-1, j+1:n]) = "new smaller";
```

It will have zeros at row i and column j. Then you just add it to "old" nxn array.

For example having array A, new array h and i=2, j=3:

```
A =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
h =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
i=2; j=3;
>> Z([1:k-1, k+1:4], [1:j-1, j+1:4]) = h
Z =
     8     1     0     6
     0     0     0     0
     3     5     0     7
     4     9     0     2
>> A = A + Z
A =
    24     3     3    19
     5    11    10     8
    12    12     6    19
     8    23    15     3
```